# Не переходит в другую папку в скрипте python

Tags: python, cmd, pyinstaller

*Новичок, не стукайте...*
Пытаюсь сделать скрипт для создания exe файла из скрипта

```
        install = input ('Что хотите обновить? ')
        os.system('cd D:/1')
        os.system('D:')
        os.system('pyinstaller -F '+ install)
        print('Готово')
        start = input('Что-то ещё? ')
        if start == "+":
            print('принял')
        elif start == "-":
            break
```

Но почему-то он переходит в нужную папку, а пытается искать в другой папке(где расположен сам exe). Выдавая такую ошибку

```
52 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.5.1
52 INFO: Python: 3.9.7
64 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0
65 INFO: wrote D:\1\dist\rab.spec
66 INFO: UPX is not available.
script 'D:\1\dist\rab.py' not found
```

Пытался сменить команду для перехода на

```
        os.system('D:')
        os.system('cd 1 ')
```

Ноль реакции...

***p.s.*** сделал скрипт для перехода в определенную папку и оттуда уже брать скрипт для билда. Так как я до этого делал уже exe файл(этого и других скриптов) он переходит в папку "dist", где и находится exe файл, через который я и пытаюсь запустить скрипт.Но по какой-то причине он не переходит в другую папку, а ищет сам скрипт в dist.

```
install = input ('Что хотите обновить? ')
        os.system('cd D:/1')
        os.system('D:')
        os.system('pyinstaller -F '+ install)
        print('Готово')
        start = input('Что-то ещё? ')
        if start == "+":
            print('принял')
        elif start == "-":
            break
```

***СПАСИБО***, os.chdir() помогло)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Функция `os.system` запускает новый процесс с интерпретатором команд, и команда `cd` выполняется не в вашем python-процессе, а внутри этого интерпретатора. Потом интерпретатор завершает работу и этот `cd` исчезает в никуда. Если вы хотите сменить папку для вашего python-процесса, нужно использовать функцию [os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)

Comment: А зачем переходить в другую папку, если можно просто указать путь? И существует ли файл D:\1\dist\rab.py?